# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::require_login()

Tags: facebook

I tried to call require login function.It shows fatal error. I downloaded the sdk from git.how to solve this issue??

Comment: Are you including the SDK?  You are really lacking in useful information to help here.  Provide some code or be more descriptive please.

Answer (score 0):

Have u downloaded the facebook.php? If then, u include those file in the page where u have called require login and create an object for that facebook class in facebook.php. Please check that facebook.php file whether it has a function related to reqire login. If not found download the latest version sdk and use it..

If u have any other doubt on this, please let me know it and i will try to explain u clearly. step by step... :)